# Is there a monerod config file to change certain settings when you run monerod in linux?

Tags: monerod, linux, monero-wallet-rpc, monejuro

I'm looking to change the default port of monerod for RPC, but I wasn't sure is there a monerod hidden config file I can put in my home folder to set the settings? And what other useful settings are there? I want to make a public node so I can connect my monerujo wallet to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create one in any directory you have permissions to access and name it anything (such as `monero.conf`). Add any of the options used on daemon startup, but leave off the leading double-dash (`--`). The examples I have seen separate key from value with an equal sign (`=`) instead of a space. (The space separator is used on the command line.)

Here's an example I found:

```
# /etc/monero/monerod.conf

# Data directory (blockchain db and indices)
data-dir=/nocow/blockchain/monero

# Log file
log-file=/var/log/monero/monerod.log
max-log-file-size=0            # Prevent monerod from managing the log files; we want logrotate to take care of that

# P2P full node
p2p-bind-ip=0.0.0.0            # Bind to all interfaces (the default)
p2p-bind-port=18080            # Bind to default port

# RPC open node
rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0            # Bind to all interfaces
rpc-bind-port=18081            # Bind on default port
confirm-external-bind=1        # Open node (confirm)
restricted-rpc=1               # Prevent unsafe RPC calls
no-igd=1                       # Disable UPnP port mapping

# Slow but reliable db writes
db-sync-mode=safe

# Emergency checkpoints set by MoneroPulse operators will be enforced to workaround potential consensus bugs
# Check https://monerodocs.org/infrastructure/monero-pulse/ for explanation and trade-offs
enforce-dns-checkpointing=1

out-peers=64              # This will enable much faster sync and tx awareness; the default 8 is suboptimal nowadays
in-peers=1024             # The default is unlimited; we prefer to put a cap on this

limit-rate-up=1048576     # 1048576 kB/s == 1GB/s; a raise from default 2048 kB/s; contribute more to p2p network
limit-rate-down=1048576   # 1048576 kB/s == 1GB/s; a raise from default 8192 kB/s; allow for faster initial sync
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create one in `~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.conf` and add any of the options used on daemon startup.

Comment: do you have an example file to base one off of?

Comment: Just run monerod --help and put whatever options you like in it (without the -- at the begining and an = then value). It's just to save running monerod with command line options every time (if you are using various options). E.g. fluffy-blocks=true

Comment: what is a generic .bitmonero.conf file to create a public node ? I'm not sure what settings I need.

Comment: You don't need a conf file, it's just there as an option if you want to customize the default settings.