# detach=1 in bitmonero.conf gives "Error parsing config file: unrecognised option 'detach' ". Why so?

Tags: monerod, bitmonero-conf

Setting `detach=1` in [bitmonero.conf](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9857/is-there-a-monerod-config-file-to-change-certain-settings-when-you-run-monerod-i) gives me

> Error parsing config file: unrecognised option 'detach'.

whereas applying `--detach` from the command line works fine. Why so?
The recognition of other parameters, when they are specified in `bitmonero.conf`, such as `p2p-bind-port=integer_of_my_choice` is without any errors.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @jtgrassie Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS